# Will 9/11 fiction get a writer into trouble with the US Government? 

Tags: fiction, characters, legal

I want to write about the very interesting topic of 'what really happened' on 9/11. How close can I possibly get to real characters and facts without getting sued?

Facts I might include in my work:

1. Transponder switching of planes over areas with little radar coverage.
2. Long delays in interceptor flights.
3. *Possible* presence of thermite in the Twin Tower rubble dust.

All this would implicitly put blame on somebody. Would that mean I would be sued the hell out of my pants? Is there a way to keep clear of getting sued if you want to write about that fateful day?

The plot of my work does not follow what happened that day. But I need to mention those characters to make it interesting. What should I do?

Comment: An important clarification - are you presenting these details as fiction or fact? Or, put another way - are you asking if you can get sued by portraying your real-life controversial interpretation, or if you can get sued by writing fiction in which a controversial interpretation (which you do not, in real life, share) is taken as fact?

Comment: I intend to only include bits of fact and couple them with fiction.. there is no denying that there were no inceptor flights to stop 9/11 planes. I wouldn't be including something like 'a 757 couldn't possibly fit inside that little hole on the Pentagon' type of accusations. Only the facts acknowledged by the US administration themselves.

Comment: The Central Intelligence Agency doesn't sue. It arrests. If you are not a U.S. native, you may need to do more research anyway so that you can write intelligently about the subject, regardless of what facts you weave into your fiction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disclaimer when writing about governmental entities](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3119/disclaimer-when-writing-about-governmental-entities)

Comment: @JohnSmithers - The two questions are similar, but this one goes more into detail on this specific situation and 9/11 issues.

Comment: So what, @NeilFein? Does that make the answers of the two questions different? Is it a detail that is relevant for the question? I don't think so.

Comment: It means that this can have potentially different answers. One of the criteria for whether a question is a duplicate is whether the answers could apply for either question. This one isn't getting any 9/11-specific answers yet, but I'd like give that a chance to happen.

Comment: I think they are similar as well.

Comment: @Capex - I've edited your title to be more representative of the issues, but please feel free to roll back if I'm not capturing your concerns correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion - stick to publically acessible facts, and express them as factual only in terms of the characters in your story. Then you are writing fiction using possibilities, and you cannot be sued for that, AFAIK. If so, I am in trouble.

You would only be in trouble legally if you were to present information as factual, and specifically make this blame people or organisations, in a book clearly intended as factual.

Think of Dan Brown. He presented wacky ideas as fact, but in a fictional context. You cannot sue him for defamation or whatever, because his story is purely fictional.

Comment: 9/11 is still a touchy subject. I personally would consult a lawyer on this.

Comment: Given that Capex has said he is only going to use "facts acknowledged by the US Administration", and incorporating them into a fiction story, I think it is probably safe. That is important. Yes 9/11 is still touchy, but I think writing fiction around it is OK. An expose of why the CIA caused it, that would be a different matter.

Comment: @NeilFein: I was thinking something similar but not sure how to phrase it. "Touchy" is an understatement.

Comment: The question was about legality. It does not mean that Capex will not then be watched day and night, and be sent to Guantanamo for jay walking.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat Honestly, that's a very real possibility even if there is no mention of CIA or any hint of a blame. Of course they won't sue me, that would be free advertising for me. But random cars crashing into me would suddenly become much more likely than winning a lottery ticket. Actually the other parties involved are much more ruthless I guess. On being a touchy topic, I can't agree more. And I have no intention to act as a reminder about a painful history. Maybe the topic is best left to be written about in another decade.

Comment: @Capex: I think leaving this subject to writers well in the future would be an excellent idea. Not because I actually fear for your life or health, but because those wounds are, frankly, still fairly raw.

Comment: If, as seems likely, you are concerned about this, then leave alone for others to write about. It might be a cross pond difference, but in the UK, we would write about it without serious worry. I can accept that in the US, feelings may be still more tender. Is it a good idea to write like this - probably, from what you have said, no, because it might attract the wrong sort of attention from the wrong people. You might have to justify yourself. It is probably not worth it. But the asked question of legal trouble is a distinct one.